# How to whitelist dynamic IP Address using Java?

Tags: java, networking, ip-address

Application IP Address is changing dynamically, so I want fetch IP address from application URL and want to whitelist using Java without using XML. Please let me know how to do ?

I have tried below code but it's contain with XML configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/foos/**").hasIpAddress("11.11.11.11")
.anyRequest().authenticated()
.and()
.formLogin().permitAll()
.and()
.csrf().disable();
}

<security:http>
    <security:form-login/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/foos/**" access="hasIpAddress('11.11.11.11')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</security:http>
```

Comment: Please show what you did?

Comment: I have updated code